# Denwer with php 5.4

Tags: denwer, php

Пытался обновить версию php на денвере до 5.4 по посту в [блоге](http://berezovskiy.org.ua/2012/03/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BE-php-5-4/).
Но почему-то выскакивает такая ошибка:
[image]

Как быть?

**Добавлено.**

Сразу не проверил, но всё работает, но ошибка всё равно после 100 запусков бесить будет, как избавиться?)

Comment: Добавить библиотеку никак?

Comment: А помоему на официальном сайте [Denwer][1] уже с обновлённым PHP появился


  [1]: http://www.denwer.ru

Comment: Вообще этот файл там есть. Вы уверены что проблема в отсутствии?

Comment: Джентльменский Набор Web-Разработчика (PHP 5.3.3, MySQL 5.1, PostgreSQL 8.4 etc.)

5.3.3 Мне не подходит.

Comment: А sorry не знал :) но ведь на сайте можно скачать отдельно обновления компонентов

Comment: У вас Apche не подходит под PHP...